# Jquery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm rebuilding some of my PhoneGap app in JavaScript to increase performance as I've been educated that jQuery is a real performance hit. I've been successful with most of it but I've come across this tricky snippet of code:

```
function expand(button) {
    $(button).parent().siblings('.details').toggle('hide');
    $(button).children().toggleClass('icon-minus');
 }
```

I noticed when this gets execute it lags on some devices. Any input on how to make this native would greatly be appreciated! Thanks!

**Updated with some reworked jQuery & my "dumbed down" html markup.**

```
function expand(button) {
   $(button).siblings('.details').toggle('hide');
   $(button).toggleClass('icon-minus');
}

<article>
   <i class='icon-plus' onclick='expand(this)'></i>
   <div class='details hide'>DETAILS for 1</div>
</article>
<article>
   <i class='icon-plus' onclick='expand(this)'></i>
   <div class='details hide'>DETAILS for 2</div>
</article>
<article>
   <i class='icon-plus' onclick='expand(this)'></i>
   <div class='details hide'>DETAILS for 3</div>
</article>
```

The articles get generated via angular ng-repeat.

Comment: Making it "native" will likely not fix any performance issues; the complexity of the approach will remain the same. (I suspect there was a down-vote because this questions requests a task: "Convert my code.")

Comment: Is there a better way to approach what this function is trying to do. I'm willing to recode it.

Comment: First find out why it is slow; is it *really* jQuery (while it does add some overhead it's rarely going to be the game-changer and there is *no point* replacing jQuery wholesale, see [the 97/3 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes)) or is the fundamental approach the problem?

Comment: FYI... native means the phone's native code, i.e. objective c for ios or java for android. JavaScript is not native code for mobile devices. There are also some lightweight jquery alternatives that provide the more common jquery functionality without the bulk and less performance hit.

Comment: I was going through a phonegap optimization slide from the phonegap developers and it recommended to write all jquery in javascript. This is why I started doing this.

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML and CSS? If so then you may be able to rework it without the need of Javascript. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KXt8g/ as a simple example.

Comment: ^Yes, I'm moving around the HTML right now trying to find a less taxing approach. I've got it down alot so far. I will update results soon. 

I like the css animation that gets called with the jquery toggle so I'm aiming to replicate that as well.

Comment: I updated what I got it down too which is definitely a bit better. Still not happy with it.

Comment: No idea what animation you are using, but you can perform animations in CSS too. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VLF6H/

Comment: jquery has a default animation with toggle, that should be easy to replicate.

Comment: Well, I can't think of anything more performant than using CSS. :)

Comment: agreed but if u look at my above code, I need it to happen on click for a button (icon with onclick)... Css doesn't have a click event.. if I used `:active`, it only works when user is holding down on button and `:focus` if the user clicks away it will revert to old css.

Comment: You could possibly style the checkboxes to look like buttons http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/p499h/ Just thoughts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the jquery source to get an idea how to the functions work.

Then "hard code" the functions into the call.

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.siblings

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.parent

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.toggleClass

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.toggle

http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.children

I can't see how much jQuery could be hurting performance in this case. I would suggest looking at how the function is called.

Contrary to what some say, jQuery is slower when compared to raw javascript. It does a lot of checks that may not be needed in your code. The key to fast jQuery is to cache objects like:

```
var objects = $('#id .class'); 
objects = .chainedjQFunctionsHere();
```

Comment: I updated with some more information with what I am trying to do.